# While updating rows in a table taking long time after every sequence of update?

Tags: mysql, database-performance, database-partitioning

this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `fa_nls_og` (
    `Incr_Dollar_YAG_pct_Chg` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Incr_U_YAG_pct_Chg` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Incr_U_YAG_Chg` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Incr_EQ_YAG_pct_Chg` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Incr_EQ_YAG_Chg` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Baseline_EQ_YAG_pct_Chg` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Baseline_EQ_YAG_Chg` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Baseline_Units_YAG_pct_Chg` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Baseline_Units_YAG_Chg` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Units_YAG_Period` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Units_YAG_pct_Chg` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Units_YAG_Chg` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `PERIOD_YEAR` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `CAT_NO` int(10) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
    /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (PERIOD_YEAR)
    SUBPARTITION BY KEY (CAT_NO) SUBPARTITIONS 12
   (PARTITION pytd VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p VALUES LESS THAN (200000) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (201401) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (201402) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (201403) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (201404) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (201405) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (201406) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (201407) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN (201408) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p16 VALUES LESS THAN (201409) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p18 VALUES LESS THAN (201410) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p20 VALUES LESS THAN (201411) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p22 VALUES LESS THAN (201412) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p24 VALUES LESS THAN (201501) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p26 VALUES LESS THAN (201502) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p28 VALUES LESS THAN (201503) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p30 VALUES LESS THAN (201504) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p32 VALUES LESS THAN (201505) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p34 VALUES LESS THAN (201506) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p36 VALUES LESS THAN (201507) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p38 VALUES LESS THAN (201508) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p40 VALUES LESS THAN (201509) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p42 VALUES LESS THAN (201510) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p44 VALUES LESS THAN (201511) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p46 VALUES LESS THAN (201512) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p48 VALUES LESS THAN (201601) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p50 VALUES LESS THAN (201602) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p52 VALUES LESS THAN (201603) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p54 VALUES LESS THAN (201604) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p56 VALUES LESS THAN (201605) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p58 VALUES LESS THAN (201606) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p60 VALUES LESS THAN (201607) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p62 VALUES LESS THAN (201608) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p64 VALUES LESS THAN (201609) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p66 VALUES LESS THAN (201610) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p68 VALUES LESS THAN (201611) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p70 VALUES LESS THAN (201612) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p72 VALUES LESS THAN (201701) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p74 VALUES LESS THAN (201702) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p76 VALUES LESS THAN (201703) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p78 VALUES LESS THAN (201704) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p80 VALUES LESS THAN (201705) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p82 VALUES LESS THAN (201706) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p84 VALUES LESS THAN (201707) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p86 VALUES LESS THAN (201708) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p88 VALUES LESS THAN (201709) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p90 VALUES LESS THAN (201710) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p92 VALUES LESS THAN (201711) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p94 VALUES LESS THAN (201712) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p96 VALUES LESS THAN (201801) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p98 VALUES LESS THAN (201802) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p100 VALUES LESS THAN (201803) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p102 VALUES LESS THAN (201804) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p104 VALUES LESS THAN (201805) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p106 VALUES LESS THAN (201806) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p108 VALUES LESS THAN (201807) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p110 VALUES LESS THAN (201808) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p112 VALUES LESS THAN (201809) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p114 VALUES LESS THAN (201810) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p116 VALUES LESS THAN (201811) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p118 VALUES LESS THAN (201812) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p144 VALUES LESS THAN (201901) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p146 VALUES LESS THAN (201902) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p148 VALUES LESS THAN (201903) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p150 VALUES LESS THAN (201904) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p152 VALUES LESS THAN (201905) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p154 VALUES LESS THAN (201906) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p156 VALUES LESS THAN (201907) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p158 VALUES LESS THAN (201908) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p160 VALUES LESS THAN (201909) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p162 VALUES LESS THAN (201910) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p164 VALUES LESS THAN (201911) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p166 VALUES LESS THAN (201912) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p120 VALUES LESS THAN (202001) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p122 VALUES LESS THAN (202002) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p124 VALUES LESS THAN (202003) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p126 VALUES LESS THAN (202004) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p128 VALUES LESS THAN (202005) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p130 VALUES LESS THAN (202006) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p132 VALUES LESS THAN (202007) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p134 VALUES LESS THAN (202008) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p136 VALUES LESS THAN (202009) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p138 VALUES LESS THAN (202010) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p140 VALUES LESS THAN (202011) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
    PARTITION p142 VALUES LESS THAN (202012) ENGINE = InnoDB
) */
```

updates on one of the column where period year and catno

first update it takes 5 sec ,2nd time updating it takes 30 min , can anyone help it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should know that we are all volunteers here, and that the presentation of your question matters. It's unreasonable to expect us to guess what your problem is; you need to be as clear as possible.  Please read this, especially the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please [edit] your question to be more clear.

Comment: There could be a range of different things causing your issue, we need to understand your row counts also does the update rule change per transaction? is this table indexed? If so what type? Please also provide your update statement.

Comment: if you see table structure there is no index added for any column , row count upto millions rows and transaction does not changes,its same for each trasnsaction : update tablename set dynamicl26=0 where period_year = 2017 and cat_no= 0;

Answer (score 0):

- Too many partitions.  After about 50, performance degrades.  (You have about 800!)
- Don't pre-build partitions; it slows down operations.
- `SUBPARTITIONs` have no performance benefit.
- Don't use `DOUBLE(m,n)` it leads to extra rounding.  Either use plain `DOUBLE` (with 16 significant digits) or `DECIMAL(m,n)` *with reasonable values for m and n*.  `DOUBLE` (with or without (m,n)) takes 8 bytes; `DECIMAL(50,4)` takes about 25 bytes!
- `int(50)` -- The `(50)` means nothing.  `INT` always takes 4 bytes.  Since it seems to be a `YEAR`, use that datatype (only 2 bytes).
- Have a `PRIMARY KEY`
- If that is your main query, have `INDEX(period_year, catno)`.

After all of that, get rid of all partitioning -- it is not providing anything useful (based on what you have said so far).  The `INDEX` will give you the speed you are missing.  My other tips help in various other ways, some of them helping directly or indirectly (eg, small = faster) with speed.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance! update its happening on one column based on partition (period_year and cat_no). I heard that partitioning is faster than indexing while giving results . but when first time transaction happpen,it takes 5 sec to gives result. next time same transaction happens ,then it takes 30 min? can you help me here @Rick james

Comment: also primary key for period and catno which will have lot of entries and it wont be unique

Comment: also primary key for period and catno which will have lot of entries and it wont be unique and there is no unique column present in the table, pls suggest how can i add primary key for this table and transaction happens same time

Comment: I really need to see the `UPDATE` statement (you can mask out the actual values if you need to).  Is the number of rows the same for the two runs?  That is, are `period` and `catno` the same for both?  The way you have it structured, it will have to scan the entire partition; so if different partitions are different sizes, ...

Comment: With or without a PK, with or without partitioning, `INDEX(period_year, catno)` would be helpful.

Comment: but there are millions of rows updating in one transaction, we tried with index but it was very slower than partition

Comment: update tablename set dynamicl26= 0 where period_year = '' and cat_no= 0 and there are millions of rows updating for each partition p1,p2,p3(periodyear) and subpartition (catno)

Comment: there is no primary key is present and no unique column, what wud be the best column that we can primary key or adding new column id will help us

Comment: Is that millions of 1-row `UPDATE` statements in a single `BEGIN...COMMIT` block?

Comment: When you don't specify a `PRIMARY KEY`, a 6-byte, hidden, number is provided as the PK.  I don't _think_ it matters _in this case_ whether you specify the PK or not.  With no 'natural PK', an `AUTO_INCREMENT` is usually used.

Comment: How big is the table, in GB?  How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  (These will help analyze whether the cache is thrashing I/O.)

Comment: 380 MB table and RAM of server is 672 G installed physical memory. I have kept Innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G @Rick James

Comment: Is that millions of 1-row UPDATE statements in a single BEGIN...COMMIT block? autocommit value is ON ,if im not wrong the one transcation automatically commit and yes millions of rows update in single transaction

Comment: If your data is so small, then most of the RAM is wasted?  Or is some other app using it?

Comment: `BEGIN` overrides `autocommit` to make it one huge transaction.  Committing in chunks of 1000 rows is about optimal.

Comment: you mean to say "transaction which should happen in chunk of 1000 rows will be optimal" do we have any configuration parameters will help it? or especially which  help in large large for transaction@ Rick James

Comment: Below 100 rows, there is a noticeable overhead for "commit".  About 1000 rows, you are into "diminishing returns" and may be reaching into "undo log" overhead.  The "curve" of performance versus chunk size is very flat; you would be hard pressed to distinguish the optimal value for all the "noise".  If it is not fast enough at 1000, then something different needs to be conjured up.